# USB cable for smart TV

Tags: usb, cable

Can I use a USB cable to connect my laptop to a Panasonic smart TV?  The cable would need to be about 15 feet long.

Comment: A USB connection between your Smart TV and Laptop seems a bit odd, what is the purpose of you doing this?

Comment: You could but it would't do anything.  Both devices would be USB hosts, you don't connect a host to another host.

Comment: Hmmm!  My brother in law uses his tv a a large monitor so he will not have to squint at the small laptop screen.  I thought he was using a USB cable but maybe he was using HDMI.  Thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect them, but maybe you cannot use them together.

Before buying the cable, read the TV manual and look for the instructions about what you want to do.

If you want to play video files stored in your notebook, you will need to install some software to allow the TV to read them through the USB port. I don't know if it will be possible.

One pen drive or external hard drive can be used to do it, but the notebook will be more difficult.

I recommend you to buy one HDMI cable to connect them (if the note have HDMI ports), it will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

A USB to HDMI or RCA external video device such as [this one seen on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1080P-Laptop-PC-USB-to-HDMI-Video-Adapter-Converter-3-5mm-Audio-Cable-HDTV-Mac-/320922155111) is an option if your laptop has no suitable video outputs. It may not work until the right driver software is installed (though this should come with it).

[image: Image of a USB to HDMI or RCA external video device.]